# Phase change of transverse waves

Tags: waves, reflection

My textbook states that a transverse wave on a string, which has a fixed end, is reflected at the fixed end and the phase is shifted by π. No further explanation is given.
Here I have plotted a wave (blue) given by $y=\sin \left( t-x \right)$ . So the reflected wave should have the equation $y=\sin \left( t+x+\pi \right)$, which is plotted in red. The resultant wave after reflection is the green plot. From what I understand, if the clamped end was at, say, $x=5$, the phase change couldn't have been π, since there would need to be a node at the clamp.
[image]
So is the phase change different for different positions of the clamp? If is use trigonometric addition and set the amplitude of the resultant wave equal to 0 at $x=5$ in the above case, I get $\pi-10$ as the phase change of the reflected wave. Is this correct?

Comment: I can't tell what the horizontal axis is in your plot.  If it is $x$, what did you choose for    $t$?   If $t$, what did you choose for $t$?  Is the clamp at $x=0$?

Comment: The horizontal axis is $x$, and its a snapshot of the waves $y=\sin \left( t-x\right)$ and $y=\sin \left( t+x+\pi \right)$ and their resultant wave at a certain time. I have not shown the clamp. My question is if the equation of the reflected wave changes with the position of the clamp.

Comment: The equation plotted in red is what the text says the equation of the reflected wave should be. I'm not sure where they assume the clamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the reflected wave should have the equation $y=\sin \left( t+x+\pi \right)$

To get this formula for the reflected wave, you assumed the reflection happens at $x=0$.

If you want to have a reflection at $x=5$, you need to shift the origin before inverting the spatial parameter.

So your incoming wave is $y = \sin(t-(x-5)-5)$, and your reflected wave is $y_r = \sin(t+(x-5)-5+\pi)$ or $y_r = \sin(t+x -10+\pi)$.

Here's the plot showing the situation at $t=0$:

[image]

Blue: incoming wave. Green: reflected wave. Red: Standing wave (superposition of incoming and reflected waves).

This shows there is indeed a node in the standing wave pattern at $x=5$.